# HTML attribute passed incomplete in a javascript function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML attribute passed incomplete in a Javascript function call

find my code below:

```
var circleName ="Andhra Pradesh";
<li><a onclick='selectCircle(this);' href='javascript:void(0);' circle="+circleName+">

<script type="text/javascript">
function selectCircle(hre) {
var circle = $(hre).attr('circle');
alert(circle);    
</script>
```

in alert i get only "Andhra" or if I pass "UP west" I get "uP" in the alert

Comment: Is this the full code? There appears to be things missing.

Comment: No this is not complete ..i am getting error in just this part

Comment: Your `<a>` tag is missing closing part i.e. </a> and your function selectCircle is missing closing bracket `}`,

Comment: It looks like you should [convert spaces into their entity](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) value to preserve them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your html:

```
<li><a onclick='selectCircle(this);' href='javascript:void(0);' circle='"+circleName+"'>
```

You are missing quotes in your circle attribute.

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt for me it is not working
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/uo4rddvm/"> Demo Here</a>

Comment: @ozil I dont know about your problem ..give me the link

Answer (score 0):

Try like this Use jquery [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/w8dfj355/)

In your code concat is wrong

```
<li><a onclick='selectCircle(this);' href='javascript:void(0);' circle='"+circleName+"'>
```

**Using Jquery**

```
$('#selectCircle').click(function(){
var circle = $(this).attr('circle');
alert(circle);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your variable (`var circleName = "Andhra Pradesh";`) should be inside the `script` block, and so should the code that builds the `li`.
2. You are building an HTML string with an attribute whose value is based on your variable, but you need to encase the single quotes inside of the double quotes (`circle='" + circleName + "'`)

```js
var circleName = "Andhra Pradesh";
var circleNameText = "Andhra Pradesh Circle"; // the text could be same as name, or different.
var $listItem = $("<li><a onclick='selectCircle(this);' href='javascript:void(0);' circle='" + circleName + "'>" + circleNameText + "</a></li>");
$("#list").append($listItem);

function selectCircle(hre) {
  var circle = $(hre).attr('circle');
  alert(circle);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='list'></ul>
```